# Run nginx server from config file not in default location

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx config file named `default-site` like so:

```
server {
    ...
}
```

somewhere in my Documents folder. Is it possible to run the server using this configuration file rather than putting it in the default `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

I tried using the `-c` flag like so:

```
sudo nginx -c ~/Documents/trustfactors/analytics/infra-ansible/roles/nginx/files/default-site
```

but I get the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /Users/william/Documents/trustfactors/analytics/infra-ansible/roles/nginx/files/default-site:5
```

Comment: Would you share default-site file?

Comment: Try the include directive. The problem you're having is your config is invalid, if you share it you may get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the complete nginx configuration there, only a virtual server configuration. You need a copy of the existing `nginx.conf`, where you will include this configuration file.